# Compiling cpp with precompiled headers

Tags: c++, g++, precompiled-headers

Suppose you have 2 files:

- `A.h` and
- `A.cpp`, where `A.cpp` includes `A.h`

You precompile your header to `A.h.gch` and delete `A.h`

Having 2 files:

- `A.cpp` and
- `A.h.gch`,

**How do you compile a final product, using g++?**

In my case, `g++` is complaining that `.h` file is nowhere to be found.

Comment: "delete A.h" Don't do that. Precompiled headers do not *replace* the original.

Comment: What is the compiler command line you use for precompiling the header, and the command line used to compile the final product? I suspect there are differences that cause `g++` to refuse to use the precompiled header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not expert, but from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header):

> GCC can only use the precompiled version if the same compiler switches are set as when the header was compiled and it may use at most one.

I've tried:

```
g++ a.h
rm a.h
g++ -c a.cpp
```

you can see if g++ is using it with:

```
g++ -H -c a.cpp

! a.h.gch
a.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that g++ would check the date of the header, to see if the gch is outdated.
To my surprise, this is not the case. I could modify and rename the header, and could still compile the cpp.

Compilation fails if certain parameters are different than when the gch has been created.
Therefore I'd assume that your compilation fails because at least one of the conditions mentioned in the [GCC precompiled header docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) is not met.

If you often switch between different compile configurations, you can use a directory containing a pch for each configuration, as described in that document.

If you just want to make sure that/if the pch is used, use the `-Winvalid-pch` option, and make sure to update the pch after each change to the header.